# UITableViewCell textLabel not showing as optional

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm currently following [Stanford's Swift course on iTunes U](https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-8-apps-swift/id961180099). I'm trying to follow the example from Lecture 10 and I'm receiving the following error on the line in the code below: `The operand of postfix '?' should have an optional type; type is 'UILabel'`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Storyboard.CellReuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    let tweet = tweets[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = tweet.text // this line throws the error
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = tweet.user.name

    return cell
}
```

However, if I remove the `?` it compiles fine. This conflicts with the example in the video (which compiles with the `?`). Plus the documentation for the [UITableViewCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/textLabel) shows that the `textLabel` is an optional type.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Storyboard.CellReuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    let tweet = tweets[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel.text = tweet.text // for some reason it wants me to treat the textLabel as a UILabel and not as an optional
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = tweet.user.name

    return cell
}
```

Can someone explain what might be causing the discrepancy?

Comment: Apple is updating their APIs wrt returning Optionals.

Comment: Apple keeps changing its Swift APIs so a lot tutorials on the web, and sometimes even the documentation becomes obsolete, until it gets updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed by installing the latest version of Xcode (version 6.2).